# lpsolve library dynamically linking

Tags: linux, cc, lpsolve

the lpsolve library has a script to build a `demo.c` file.

```
#This script expects to be located in a subdirectory of a subdirectory of the base lpsolve files
cc -DEXPLICIT -I../.. -O3 demo.c explicit.c -lm -ldl -o demoe ../../lpsolve55/liblpsolve55.so
opts='-O3'
opts=''

cc -I../.. $opts demo.c implicit.c -lm -ldl -o demoi ../../lpsolve55/liblpsolve55.a
```

The name of the file is `ccc` and the content is displayed above.
From Terminal how do you call this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call this script using

```
sh ccc
```

This information is also contained in file **demo/readme.txt**:

> To build the program under Linux/Unix, use sh ccc